# Understanding of SVC and it's impact

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I would like to know about "SVC" error keyword in marklogic.

- What is SVC?
- What is it's impact?
- Is it a critical error or not?
- At what level it is? I mean to say, Is it at database level or application level or both ?
- How can we rectify this?

Comment: I expect that the severity and the mitigation depend on the specific SVC error message received and its root cause. To put it the other way, I don't think there is a general answer that applies to all SVC error messages in all circumstances. For the list of SVC error messages, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/messages/SVC-en

Answer (score 4):

The [Marklogic documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/messages/intro#id_pgfId-1059248) says:

> **SVC** |  MarkLogic Server service layer, usually related to OS or system and network protocol errors.

The meaning of each error code and a suggested solution can be found [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/messages/SVC-en).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion both of you. I understand it depends on specific SVC error message but the point here is what exactly is SVC error? What defines SVC.